# JSON merge(update)|filter|increment ID

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, nightmare

I'm working on website scraping solution with nightmare.js.

I'm getting 24/7 new JSON files from XHReq (on server, there is 24/7 changing filters and getting new JSON files from XHReq - ajax website)...

Every JSON has 50  objects (id from 0 to 49). I need solution which will make "MASTER JSON", with all objects, from all JSON files (asigning new IDs - for exp.

If there is in "MASTER JSON" last object with ID 763, new objects from new JSON - with IDs from 0 to 49 must have new IDs from 764 to 813), 
and I need to check is there same object from earlier JSONs (to not add again).

Comment: That's not how SO works: you are supposed to make a fair attempt yourself, then come with what you have so far to get more hints or help with particular issues. What you've done so far: posted a task somebody is supposed to do for you for free.

Comment: I don't want that someone do this for me, I just want couple suggestions about possible ways to do it, because I'm new with this...

Answer (score 1):

In order to do that you can just store a variable somewhere containing last id and when merging the jsons, overwriting the id using the new id like this:

```
let lastId = 1;
let items  = [{ id: 33, value: '', id: 55, value: ''}];
let processed = [];

for(let item of items) {
  item.id = ++lastId;
  processed.push(item);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try something like this, and will update with result.

Comment: Upvoted because you read the gibrish question and replied with a clean answer.